# Ext Js Drop down combo box within iframe asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, extjs

I have created an iframe within Ext pop up window.

```
var htmlContent = '<iframe src="' + currentURL + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
    win = new Ext.Window({
        title: 'Information',
        height:600,
        width: 700,
        html: htmlContent,
        closable: true,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        style: 'windowstyle1',
        cls: 'windowstyle1',
    });

    win.show();
```

The current URL is a `asp.net` aspx page.
Inside asp.net page I have `asp:DropDown` list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_ChkType" runat="server" CssClass="select" >
                                <asp:ListItem Text="drop1" Value="P"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="drop2" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have to change the look and feel of the `asp:dropdown` list similar to Ext Js Combo box.
So in the aspx page I have added below code to tranform the dropdown to ext combo box but it's not working.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
            alert("hi");
            var transformed = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                fieldLabel: 'Select a single state',
                typeAhead: true,
                transform: 'stateSelect',//don't know wht to specify here.
                width: 135,
                forceSelection: true
            });
 });
```

Only alert `hi` is working, nothing else. Could anyone help me with this?
I have also tried to modify the same using `css` for select class but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the instance, and it sits somewhere in the object tree. But you want it to be rendered into the DOM tree. So you have to provide to your component a render target, e.g.

```
renderTo:Ext.getBody()
```

or, if you have a `<div id="test"></div>` you want it inside,

```
renderTo:Ext.get("test")
```

Example usage:

```
var transformed = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    renderTo:Ext.getBody()
```

Comment: Hi, I have added this also.  '<div class="select" id="droplist">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_ChkType" runat="server"  >
                                <asp:ListItem Text="drop1" Value="P"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="drop2" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                          </div>' and renderTo:Ext.get("droplist"). But it's not working. Is it because of the iframe inside which I am trying to change this dropdown?

Comment: I have also tried this one. `renderTo:'droplist'`. Nothing is displying in that div. Even this s also not working. `renderTo:Ext.get("droplist")`.

Comment: -my div resides in below structure: `<body>
  <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder>
      <form id="id1">
 <fieldset>
   <div id="droplist">` in the aspx page.